# jquery calling datepicker on dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to call the datepicker on dynamically created elements but doesn't work. I know that my format is not correct. Anyone knows how?

```
    $("body").on('click', '.startNew', function() {
        $(".startNew").datepicker({
           dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd 00:00:00",
           numberOfMonths: 2,
           onSelect: function(selected) {
             $(".endNew").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
           }
        });
    });
    $("body").on('click', '.endNew', function() {
       $(".endNew").datepicker({ 
           dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd 00:00:00",
           numberOfMonths: 2,
           onSelect: function(selected) {
              $(".startNew").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
           }
       });
    });
```

Comment: we need to see where you are creating the element, include that source and the markup as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated. Try to change (body -> document; click -> focus)

from

```
$(body).on('click',".startNew", function(){
    $(".startNew").datepicker({

$(body).on('click',".endNew", function(){
    $(".endNew").datepicker({
```

to

```
$(document).on('focus',".startNew", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({

$(document).on('focus',".endNew", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
```

Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/17z84aw3/)

**HTML**

```
Start: <input class='endNew'><br/><br/>
End: <input class='startNew'>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('focus',".startNew", function(){
  $(this).datepicker({
    dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd 00:00:00",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $(".endNew").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
    }
  });
});


$(document).on('focus',".endNew", function(){
  $(this).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd 00:00:00",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $(".startNew").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: this wouldn't work on the dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first click is initializing the plugin, but that won't show the datepicker since the datepicker click handler is added after the click event. So

```
$("body").on('click', '.startNew', function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker')) {
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd 00:00:00",
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $(".endNew").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
            }
        }).datepicker('show');
    }
});
$("body").on('click', '.endNew', function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker')) {
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd 00:00:00",
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $(".startNew").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
            }
        }).datepicker('show');
    }
});
```

In this case, you are trying to initialize the plugin lazily, but a better solution will is to initialize the plugin after the target element `.startNew` and `.endNew` is created.

Comment: is there a way to call the datepicker through on click? or how can I re-initialize the plugin after .startNew and .endNew?